# Definite integration of a exponential function mixed with rational functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, exponential-function

Suppose $a>0$ , I am interested in a solution of the following definite integral:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\exp({-az})}{z \sqrt{z^2-1}}{\,dz}$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We notice that $I'(a)=-\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-az}}{\sqrt{z^2-1}}dx$, which, by letting $x=\cosh t$, can be [rewritten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) as $-\text{Bessel K}_0(a)$. Then, integrating with regards to *a*, we get $I(a)=\dfrac\pi2\bigg\{1-a~\bigg[K_0(a)L_{-1}(a)+$ $+K_1(a)L_0(a)\bigg]\bigg\}$, where *L* is the [Struve function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. The minor mistake is that you did not consider the constant of integration.

Comment: @MojtabaGolshani: Thank you for the heads up!